# How to do different things if a value is or is not valid for the 'static lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe

For a niche bit of code (dealing with custom allocators), I need to keep track of methods that return `T` that could potentially be holding on to a reference to the custom allocation.

For those references, I need to clean up differently than for `T` that does not contain any references (essentially, things that are completely owned).

However, I cannot find a way to check if T is `'static`. I know that lifetimes aren't available at runtime, so I would like to monomorphize for `T: 'static` and for `T: 'a` where `'a` is a lifetime I can give out.

I have tried this bit of code (taken from the specialization hacks)

```rust
struct Wrap<'a, T: 'a> {
    _t: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
    t: T,
}
impl<'a, T: 'a> Wrap<'a, T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            _t: PhantomData {},
            t,
        }
    }
}

trait NotStatify {
    fn is_static(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}
impl<'a, T: 'a> NotStatify for &Wrap<'a, T> {}

trait Statify {
    fn is_static(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
impl<T: 'static> Statify for Wrap<'static, T> {}

#[test]
fn test_statify() {
    let g = "abc".to_string();

    dbg!((&&&Wrap::new(g.as_str())).is_static());
    dbg!((&&&Wrap::new(10)).is_static());
}
```

But this, unfortunately, does not work. How would I go about crafting a function that takes T and returns true/false depending on if T holds onto references?

Even if you think is an XY problem, I would still like some ideas on how to get `is_static` working.